# How do I programatically create an event handler with the name as a variable?

Tags: c#

For example:

```
MySlider.ValueChanged += new RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<double>(Slider_ValueChanged);
```

The above is well and good except that without a 'Slider_ValueChanged' method present it won't compile.  More than that if I want to programatically create several sliders I might want to give them different handlers with different names.

Ideally I'd like to do something like:

```
var x = some_handler;
MySlider.ValueChanged += new RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<double>(x);
```

The basic idea is just to return programatically preconfigured panels of sliders on demand that I can just swap in and out depending on user selected options.  The actual implementation of the event handlers for the programatically created sliders will already be present in the project.

Corrected the code as per Matthew Walton's answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer's already in your question, except your code's not quite right.

```
var x = some_handler;
MySlider.ValueChanged += new RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<double>(x);
```

Would attach `some_handler` to the event. From this, it follows that you can write a method which takes a handler function and other information for the slides as a parameter and uses that to set up the event handler and other relevant data and maybe return a slide object or store it in a collection or whatever you need to do.

You might also want to look into anonymous functions and lambdas, which can be a useful way of constructing similar-but-different event handlers for different objects created inside a loop.